# No persistence after the server's restart using HashMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-threads

I just had some code review for back-end Spring Boot application I have written and while I understood most of it, I cannot wrap my head around one comment. Namely:

> The status of the application is persisted in a non-thread-safe HashMap and therefore there is no persistence after the server's restarts.

The code involved storing data in FakeDatabase, so I simply created Database interface and made FakeDatabase implements Database. FakeDatabase was storing information in a HashMap. Full code below:

```
@Component
public class FakeDatabase implements Database {

private HashMap<String, Player> db;

public FakeDatabase() {
    db = new HashMap<>();
}

public void clearDb() {
    db = new HashMap<>();
}

@Override
public Player getPlayer(String username) {
    return db.get(username);
}

@Override
public Player createNewPlayer(String username) {
    db.put(username, PlayerFactory.createPlayer(username));
    return db.get(username);
}

@Override
public void updatePlayer(Player player) {
    db.put(player.getUsername(), player);
}

@Override
public HashMap<String, Player> getDatabase() {
    return db;
}

@Override
public Game getOngoingGame(Player player) {
    return db.get(player.getUsername()).getCurrentGame();
}
```

}

Would simply changing HashMap to ConcurrentHashMap be ok? I think I simply don't understand why there is no persistence after server's restart when data is being stored in a non-thread-safe collection?

Comment: Why don't you ask the reviewer? But erm, why a hashmap? Usually we use H2 as fake database.

Comment: It was code review for a position I have applied and that was the feedback I have received. It also didn't come directly from the reviewer but via a middleman. Yes, I've never used H2, and just thought hashmap would be enough to store simple 'Name, Object' data.

Comment: Maybe that's your issue then. They probably wanted to see how you would persist the data, and by using a non-threadsafe hashmap instead of the standard JPA layer, you made a mistake.

Comment: Isn't the data persisted all the same though? I mean I do understand that Hashmap is not thread-safe but how does it connect to server's restarts?

Comment: With JPA and the H2 database, the data is not persisted through reboots. But since you use JPA, you just have to switch H2 for something else (ie. Hibernate), and suddenly, without changing your code, the data is persisted. The point here is, you could make it persisted with just a configuration change.